# No se como recorrer este array en React

Tags: array, reactjs

Desde mi backend recupero este array:

```
  {
    id: 1,
    seats: 4,
    positionX: 0,
    positionY: 0,
    qrURL: 'http://192.168.1.128:3000/clientCart?mesa=1',
    createdAt: 2022-06-15T11:36:12.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-06-15T11:36:12.000Z,
    'products.id': 4,
    'products.name': 'Flamenquitos',
    'products.description': 'Rulo de jamon York y queso Mozzarella que se te derretirá en la boca.',  
    'products.price': 1.3,
    'products.allergens': '[{"label":"Lacteos","value":"lacteos"}]',
    'products.img': 'flamenquitos.jpg',
    'products.section': 1,
    'products.createdAt': 2022-06-12T10:31:21.000Z,
    'products.updatedAt': 2022-06-12T10:31:21.000Z,
    'products.sectionId': null,
    'products.cart.qty': 3,
    'products.cart.createdAt': 2022-06-16T11:12:23.000Z,
    'products.cart.updatedAt': 2022-06-17T08:38:30.000Z,
    'products.cart.productId': 4,
    'products.cart.tableId': 1
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    seats: 4,
    positionX: 0,
    positionY: 0,
    qrURL: 'http://192.168.1.128:3000/clientCart?mesa=1',
    createdAt: 2022-06-15T11:36:12.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-06-15T11:36:12.000Z,
    'products.id': 5,
    'products.name': 'Patatas fritas',
    'products.description': 'Patatas bravas con salsa alioli o brava',
    'products.price': 1.45,
    'products.allergens': '[{"label":"Ninguno","value":"ninguno"}]',
    'products.img': 'descarga.jfif',
    'products.section': 1,
    'products.createdAt': 2022-06-12T10:32:31.000Z,
    'products.updatedAt': 2022-06-12T10:32:31.000Z,
    'products.sectionId': null,
    'products.cart.qty': 1,
    'products.cart.createdAt': 2022-06-17T08:38:31.000Z,
    'products.cart.updatedAt': 2022-06-17T08:38:31.000Z,
    'products.cart.productId': 5,
    'products.cart.tableId': 1
  }]
```

Mi problema es que necesito recupera el products.name y el products.price para renderizarlos en el frontend. Y además para poder hacer alguna función que me calcule el precio total del carro de la compra.

La cosa es que he probado con cart.map((product,index) => pero solo consigo llegar hasta los valores que no llevan products. delante.

He intentado recorre primero el array de cart que es que lleva todo lo mostrado anteriormente y luego recorrer el de products pero no soy capaz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en el map ese prueba con esto

```
 cart.map((product, index)=>{
      const name = product["products.name"];
      console.log(name);
      return x;
 })
```

vamos, que cuando hay puntos en las propiedades o quieres acceder mediante una variable hay que poner el nombre de la variable del objeto y luego entre corchetes el nombre de la propiedad que quieres(siempre tiene que ser un string)

Comment: Gracias, en principio me ha servido. Puedo saber si esta información la puedo encontrar en alguna documentación o algo, porque me he vuelto loco para solucionar esto.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects aquí te lo explica. Un saludo